# Separating string.xml in an android application

Tags: android, android-resources

Is there any way to separate string.xml in android application. In my case, I have 5 big modules (that I will create) like usersModule, gisModule, settingsModule, rolesModule and operationsModule. Each module has lots of activities. That means string.xml will contain all these modules string values. So I would like to create following hierarchy:

```
-res
|---->values
|     |---->usersModule-en 
|     |      |---->string.xml
|     |---->usersModule-tr 
|     |      |---->string.xml
|     |---->rolesModule-en 
|     |      |---->string.xml
|     |---->rolesModule-tr 
|           |---->string.xml
|---->style.xml
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try?  Did it work?  If not what kind of problem did you have?

Comment: Is this a translation `-en`, `-tr`?, Use `values-en`, else I think you can has mulit xml files in the values, I think the Android not set a big point on the file name, I think Android read all XML files and join this to one big here?

Answer (score 2):

Base one my comment:

Is this a translation `-en`, `-tr`?, Use `values-e`n, else I think you can has mulit xml files in the values, I think the Android not set a big point on the file name, I think Android read all XML files and join this to one big XML file?
You can try this?

```
-res
|---->values
|     |---->style.xml
|---->values-en
|     |---->usersModule.xml
|     |---->rolesModule.xml
|---->values-tr
|     |---->usersModule.xml
|     |---->rolesModule.xml
```

Comment: It did not work. Also android did not allow me to define same values in multiple xml files.

Comment: Ok, in some case while I create firefox addons or bigger Javascript I use my one builder to join one or more files, can it be a help for get a working sulation?

Comment: @demdem you cannot `define same values in multiple xml` its against the way android works. All string values are auto-generate R.class so as to reference `R.string.something` from anywhere in your project

Answer (score 0):

You can separate it into multiple files but you can specifically attach one file to a module; therefore you cannot have the same name refers to different values for different modules.

What you probably need to do is to separate it into multiple files but add a prefix indicating the desired module to each variable.